# Tools a Windows administrator cannot live without

Tags: windows

As a Windows administrator, what tools do you feel you cannot live without?

Answer (score 40):

3rd party tools are great, but before I start there, the basic ones you get with the system:

- Computer Management
- Event Viewer
- Services Console
- Perfmon
- Active Directory Users and Computers
- Active Directory Domains and Trusts
- Active Directory Sites and Services
- [Group Policy Management Console](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887&displaylang=en) (okay, so you download this one)
- The command line itself with

  - netstat
  - nbtstat
  - ipconfig
  - net
  - findstr
  - netsh
- Internet Explorer/Firefox
- Scripting tool like VBScript/PowerShell/[Perl](http://www.activestate.com/)
- Notepad

Other Tools:

- Sysinternals [PSTools Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx)
- Sysinternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- Sysinternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)
- [Joe Richards' free tools](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/index.htm) for ActiveDirectory
- Microsoft Office OneNote

Comment: I *love* OneNote.  I'm astonished that MS only made it available in Office Enterprise;  it should be in every downlevel edition!

Comment: Notepad itself isn't worth much. Notepad2 or Notepad++ offer greater options and much more possibilities, even for everyday users.

Answer (score 32):

[SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

I can't live without PowerShell.

Answer (score 14):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) is great for finding out how all your disk space it getting used.

Answer (score 10):

I always post this one, but it remains true.  [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is the best folder & file diff program.  It is so ridiculously useful for maintenance work and updating, plus it does built-in FTP

Comment: I held out against the move to Beyond Compare, sticking with WinMerge for years. Recently I tried an old copy of BC and have been kicking myself for weeks that I didn't change sooner. BC is hands-down the best merging/compare tool I've ever seen.

Comment: Try Araxis Merge. Costs more, but if you can afford it, it's worth its weight in gold.. or it's filesize in gold, at least

Answer (score 10):

Never underestimate the power of a really good text editor. I've used [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) for years and couldn't live without it. I've tried moving to Notepad++, Editplus, and a few other text editors and I always end up frustrated and back using UltraEdit.  You can also get a U3 version that lives on a flash drive.

Comment: UE is a great text editor plus it includes syntax highlighting, hex editing and diff tools...

Comment: The UE developer is also extremely responsive to requests to add features. Definitely on my list of apps I can't live without.

Answer (score 10):

[**Robocopy.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)

Recursive copying with solid reporting and allows you to update changed only. Used to be part of the windows resource kit, but i think it's distributed with Vista now.

Comment: Just confirming that it is distributed with Vista.

Comment: Try RichCopy, also from Microsoft, but GUI-based and more options than RoboCopy.  I've used the fcopy tool on a number of occasions as well to good effect when copying ridiculously large files over the WAN.

Answer (score 7):

- ProcessExplorer
- PS Tools
- Perl
- Perfmon
- TextPad/Notepad++
- Terminal Services
- Cygwin

Answer (score 7):

A Linux LiveCD (Knoppix preferably)

And processexplorer

Answer (score 6):

The SysInternals suite, live edition:

http://live.sysinternals.com/

hexedit or another hex editor.

Answer (score 6):

WMIC lets you do pretty much anything to any networked windows computer.

Some fun things to try:

```
wmic computersystem get name
```

What user is currently logged into the system:

```
wmic netlogin get name,lastlogon
```

Users who have logged into a system, and when they last logged in:

```
wmic os get lastbootuptime
```

When was the last time the machine booted; (do you have a machine not getting updates?)

```
wmic product get name,verion
```

Finds applications installed with a specific name:

```
wmic product where 'name = "%Product Name%"' get name
```

Also remember you can run these on networked systems:

```
wmic /node:"computername1" os list brief
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd throw 7-zip into the pool. Free/Open source and opens most compression formats. I use it often for moving files from one server to another (updates and/or images).

Answer (score 3):

These are more for the desktop/laptop power users:

- [safarp](http://wistinga.online.fr/safarp/): small and fast Add/Remove Programs
- [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/): keystroke launchyer
- [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console): multi-tabbed cmd.exe, (and then some)
- [jkdefrag (portable)](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jkdefrag_portable):lite-weight defragger
- [AnVir task manager](http://www.anvir.com/taskmanager/): manager for running processes, services, and startup programs (commercial but has a lite free version).
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net): Probably best text-editor available for windows.
- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/): visual diff/merge tool

Answer (score 3):

Batch files :-)

Answer (score 3):

shutdown - can shut down a non-responding host remotely

```
shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m <machine>
```

taskkill - kill processes from the commandline

```
taskkill /pid <pid>
```

psexec - the windows equivalent of ssh (from sysinternals, as previously noted)

Comment: Psexec is not the windows equivalent of ssh. It provides no encryption, no interactive session, no arbitrary port forwarding, etc. Useful but not ssh.

Comment: eek, standing corrected...

Answer (score 3):

Total Commander - Norton Commander look-a-like for Windows. I use this all the time, it's simply the best (!) file manager. Also it's shareware, so if you can live with a startup nag-screen it's free.

Ultraedit - Not free, but nothing beats this text editor. Once you go down the path of ultraedit, there's no turning back.

putty - It just works.

Comment: +1 for total commander and utraedit, first thing I install.

Answer (score 3):

TreeSizeFree for figuring out what's using all your storage space.

http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml

Comment: How does this compare to [WinDirStat](http://serverfault.com/a/3659/69936)?

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to get and install the whole Cygwin [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) are useful. It's nice to fire up cmd and use grep, wget, tail, etc.

[sniffer](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what exactly is happening on the wire [ unless you can tap somewhere on the switch with port mirroring].

[Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) for those like me who still prefer console rather over Windows Explorer. and yeah - it's open source now! Ready to use builds are [here](http://www.farmanager.com/nightly.php).

Notepad++ was already mentioned, but [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) - not. It's very useful Notepad replacement. It has syntax hilight, block operations, different encoding.

Comment: +1, as I'd just posted (now deleted as it's a dupe) the exact same thing regarding GNU Utilities for Win 32 and not needing Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

- [Wireshark](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Aen.wikipedia.org+wireshark&cts=1261570105189&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) for sniffing
- [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) for text editing
- [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/%28S%28sniknobncxssxdylxx00lh55%29%29/MainPage.ashx) for remote connections (no longer developed since 2009)

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Installer Cleanup Utility** - saved my bacon multiple times.

**Visual C# Express** - really!  The .NET framework has a LOT of useful classes for automating admin tasks, and I've rolled my own small army of useful utilities.

Answer (score 2):

[Ultra Vnc SC](http://www.uvnc.com/addons/singleclick.html) a free remote desktop tool.
Some features: You only need one exe to pass to client, no install, Can be customized and You also can translate this tool, got a file transfer and chat.

Comment: You don't even need an exe. Just use your web browser.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) or its non-free version, File Locator Pro, to be much much more effective than the basic "Search" function of Windows (which was/is broken on XP)

Comment: Its broken on Vista, still, as well.

Answer (score 2):

A new open source to alternative to ProcessExplorer is [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/).

You can install it or just run it off a thumb drive. If you install it you can take advantage of some of the special features. On such feature is a kernel mode driver that acts as a proxy to query process information. This is apparently to avoid UAC prompts in Vista. Another feature is the ability to launch ProcessHacker instead of task manager from the ctrl+alt+delete menu. Finally, you can set ProcessHacker to run at login.

Answer (score 2):

I have been testing [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) for IT management (inventory, monitoring, reporting, tracking). So far, made my life easier, so let's toss it on the pile.

Answer (score 1):

I live by [TaskInfo](http://www.iarsn.com/taskinfo.html), an integrated utility that beats Task Manager and Systems Information hands down.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd say http://ratsauce.sourceforge.net/ but then I would say that, wouldn't I :-)

Comment: Lots of those tools seem like reimplementations of consecrated tools. For example, how is httpgrabber different from wget -S? `reconcile` seems like a particular case of BeyondCompare. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

testdisk - saved my ass a when my raid screwed up, was able to copy the data off it to another drive even though it wasn't showing up in windows. now i can't live without it.

Answer (score 1):

Logparser is a must.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop / Terminal Services

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that make my life easier:

[Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/) - multi tab terminal services/remote desktop client.

and

[Nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) - network scanner extraordinaire

Answer (score 1):

RD tabs http://www.avianwaves.com/Tech/Tools/RDTabs/  is a great RDP replacement.  It allows saving connections like bookmarks, tabs, pop-outs, screen capture!  Works really well!

Answer (score 0):

- Active Directory - if you manage a domain this is your best friend. It centralizes all control over users/computers/printers/groups in your organizational unit into one program.
- gpedit - the group policy editor, allows you to easily manage registry entries for groups of users at a higher level.
- regedit - Great for making lower level tweaks to the system not available through the group policies.

Answer (score 0):

I still find myself firing up [Sequoia View](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview//) to spot the massive temp files/caches that can otherwise lie unnoticed on a volume.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the regular Windows MMC tools and OS native support tools, these are a few I use regularly. Sysinternals, Resource Kit tools, WinDBG, WMI scripts, Performance & reliability monitor and PowerShell scripts

Answer (score 0):

Heh... Norton Comander..
I like console (since DOS/Windows 3.x) and i use FAR Manager ([farmanager.com](http://farmanager.com)) as my file manager for a long time.

Now new version (2.0) with Unicode support(!) is availible. And this version not shareware, it's FREE (BSD-like license).
It's still in "alpha" and a bit tricky to install but fully working (even x64).

Answer (score 0):

More votes for PowerShell, Notepad++, PuTTY, pscp, Cygwin, sdelete, WinDirStat, and System Internals.

Also some sort of Remote control software be it UltraVNC, RDP, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

nircmd.exe

Invaluable command line tool I primarily use for killing programs and processes although it does allow a fairly high degree of control over hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) for text editing and [Servant Salamander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altap_Salamander) as file manager. Unfortunately, Salamander is a commercial product, but it is exceptionally good for working with files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

XCopy (although RoboCopy is more capable) and Ping (cmd), along with .bat files for scripting.

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/16080/69936) says RichCopy is even more capable.

Answer (score 0):

[Richcopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RichCopy), a released tool that used to be used internally in Microsoft. It's a ultimate copying tool that is much better than robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

RDtabs from Avian Waves for managing and organising RDP connections

Answer (score 0):

Terracopy or Richcopy.  Quick file transfers.  Scored points at my new job by mentioning this to my boss!

Answer (score 0):

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) to run some kind of operations with easy way to check if the tasks runs ok or not, parallelize, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

- Notepad2
- Executor
- BgInfo (on all servers)
- LPD.exe
- NirCmd
- Blat

Answer (score 0):

Bart PE, with a large assortment of plug-ins. Not so much for day-to-day use but for all those times when things go wrong and normal tools won't help or when something can't be achieved while the regular OS is running.

Perl. Tools such as logparser might be OK for some jobs but Perl has no limits.

Robocopy. In my opinion the best readily available copy utility for Windows. If you have a copy/move/sync operation that you can't do with Robocopy it's time to read the manual again.

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/16080/69936) says that RichCopy is much better than RoboCopy.

Answer (score 0):

[Joeware](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/) tools and Sysinternals

Answer (score 0):

For Sysadmins that have a laptop, I would add  [NetProfiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/)  .

Also, the website  http://portablefreeware.com  is absolutely awesome.

Answer (score 0):

TextPad is great.
VirtuaWin is fantastic if one is a fan of virtual desktops.
PuTTY
UltraVNC (because VNC will need to be used eventually, even despite RDP)
I personally like using Cygwin over cmd/command for console
Definitely Wireshark
All of the Administrator Tools that come with Windows

Answer (score 0):

smsniff from NIRSOFT. The quick network sniffer.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html

Fiddler a good HTTP debugging porxy with really good SSL support
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop Manager is awesome, It centralize all my remote connections (Including RDP, Putty, SQL Server, HTTP Interfaces, (S)FTP, CIFS shares, OpenVPN connections...

It's really a must have, all this for free, but the enterprise edition allows you some nice thing like storing connections settings in a database to push modifications to the others admins)

http://remotedesktopmanager.com/