# Best utilities for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools a Windows administrator cannot live without](https://serverfault.com/questions/3482/tools-a-windows-administrator-cannot-live-without)

Hey all,

Just like the title suggests, I am looking for the utilities you use most when setting up a Windows Server 2008 box.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx) suite of utilities are universally handy, but I find myself using [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) most often. Those two get a home on nearly every Windows system I build.

Comment: Definitely agree with the recommendation for the Sysinternals suite.  Process Explorer and Process Monitor are priceless, as are psexec and... well, really, it's all priceless.

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't put utilities onto a server. I do like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html), which allows you to mount an ISO file as if it were a CD-ROM drive.
I also like FreeUndelete or Recuva.  When needed, TeraCopy or RoboCopy are nice, too.