# Windows diagnostic tools

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools a Windows administrator cannot live without](https://serverfault.com/questions/3482/tools-a-windows-administrator-cannot-live-without)

I just joined a small computer lab which basically uses all Windows boxes and a few Windows Sever 2003. Coming from a *nix background I am missing all the nice tools that we have for diagnosis and troubleshooting. My question is what are the safe, free (not terribly concerned if it is like beer or freedom -both acceptable) tools out there that Windows system admins use for their day to day troubleshooting (network, applications, servers etc).

I am aware of the tools that come with Windows (and their limited capabilites) - so my query is with what do you fill in your arsenal? (may be a list of win versions of tools that come in standard linux distros)

Comment: Pose a few example troubleshooting scenarios where the standard tools are inadequate?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=windows+tools

Comment: The vagueness was totally intentional to maximize suggestions, and @l0c0b0x your observation is spot on. I was actually looking for such a discussion and finally summarize the contextually what tools are available for the two platforms.

Answer (score 3):

They are semi-developer-oriented, but the [sysinternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) are among the best and most useful tools available.

Comment: I don't think that I would characterize them as developer-oriented, to be honest. I'm an admin, and I've been using them for about 8-9 years. Helpful all the time.

Comment: :) fair enough. let's just call them awesome for everyone

Comment: +1 Given the vagueness of the question, the Sysinternals Suite is probably the best answer.

Comment: I use those tools regularly as an admin but can't recall ever having used them as a developer. Perhaps because that's not what they're for.

Comment: @Jeff: vagueness was totally intentional to maximize suggestions. But coming to think of it, I'll try to edit the question and make it less vague.

Answer (score 0):

Besides sysinternals, I would also add Wireshark, Spinrite (not free but worth it), and a live boot CD with various recovery and imaging tools.